# Azure durable function - unable to return a bean with @JsonProperty from activity function

Tags: java, azure, jackson, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Azure function is in java and I am using JDK17.

I am trying to return a java bean from my activity function to the orchestrator and I get the exception

```
**WARNING: The orchestrator failed with an unhandled exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected failure in the task execution**
```

I do not see any more details in the stack trace.

The java bean that I am trying to return is:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthMessage {
    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    String accessToken;
    String id;
    String tokenType;
}
```

If I remove the annotation @JsonProperty("access_token"), everything works fine. However I need this annotation to parse my json/regenerate my output json.

Anybody knows how to overcome this issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome this issue by removing `@JsonProperty` from the java beans and specifying snakeCase conversion globally using object mapper as below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

As I was using @JsonProperty to convert a few fields to snakeCase, and it is common for all my beans, this option unblocked me.

However, if a field has to be renamed by using `@JsonProperty`, we get the exception mentioned in the question.